# TouchableHighLight onPress inside a map function in react native

Tags: scope, react-native, map-function

I have an array of images that I want to display in a component in react native.
I use map function to iterate over the array and display it. I also have a delete button on top of the image.
The relevant code is :

```
      this.state.imgs.map(function(img,i){
        return (
          <View style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center', height:75, width:75, borderRadius:25}}>
            <Image style={{position:'absolute',resizeMode:'cover', top:0,left:0, borderRadius:38,height:75, width:75, opacity:0.5}} source={{uri: img.path }} />
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.removeItem(i)}>
              <Image style={{}} source={require('./Images/images_asset65.png')} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
          );
      })
```

The problem is the TouchableHighlight, where I have an event, when the event fires I get an error regarding "this" (undefined is not a function).
I know this is a scope problem but I cant figure it out.
Is the use of an arrow function is correct here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use `this` inside your map function, you have to change to an arrow function so `this` points to the outer scope.

```
  this.state.imgs.map((img, i) => {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center', height:75, width:75, borderRadius:25}}>
        <Image style={{position:'absolute',resizeMode:'cover', top:0,left:0, borderRadius:38,height:75, width:75, opacity:0.5}} source={{uri: img.path }} />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.removeItem(i)}>
          <Image style={{}} source={require('./Images/images_asset65.png')} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      );
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `function` keyword in your code, then you lose the context and `function` creates its own. If you use `function` it is better not to forget binding these functions with `bind(this)` so that these functions share the same context. So in your relevant code you should change your last line to `}.bind(this))`. It is better to remember using `bind(this)` somehow when using the `function` keyword, even the better option is not using `function` and stick with the goodies comes with ES6. Last but not least one should always read [docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)